# how to make style like attached image in android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

**I am getting issues while creating the bottom line below.**

I have tried this code but the corner radius not working on tabs. and if I put more radius value then the red line is visible on the top left and right corner, which I don't want. please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="-6dp"
        android:left="-6dp"
        android:right="-6dp"
        android:bottom="@dimen/dimen1">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#e41919"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Click on below link to view the expected design image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wd6I.png

Comment: where is the attached image ?

Comment: open this url 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysbPQ.png

Comment: also attach an image showing the output you're getting

Comment: @SuryaPrakashPandey Currently what are you using for this design a TabLayout?

Comment: Use textviews instead of tablayout make its clicklisteners and change drawables on button click

Comment: TabLayout is also child of view. So it is not necessary to use tablayout here. The only reason to use tablayout is its buit-in style, indicator and animations etc. If there is possibility to using any other view you can go ahead because user is not concerned about whether you user textview or tablayout here.